# I am trying to read an image into a folder and store it in an array, but I get an index error

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, opencv

Can't I save the pixel data of an image to a list?

```py
GmdMiss_Folder = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), '..', 'Photo', 'GMD Miss')
GmdMiss_List = os.listdir(GmdMiss_Folder)
```

```py
for i in range(0, len(GmdMiss_List)):
    Img_Miss_List[i] = np.array(cv2.imread(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), GmdMiss_Folder, GmdMiss_List[i]), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE))
```

IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is at `Img_Miss_List`. Without content, I assume you created an empty list like this:

```
Img_Miss_List = []
```

so you can only append an empty list, not use index.

How about try:

```
Img_Miss_List = []
for i in range(0, len(GmdMiss_List)):
    Img_Miss_List.append(np.array(cv2.imread(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), GmdMiss_Folder, GmdMiss_List[i]), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)))
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can store arbitrary objects in python lists, so it should not be a problem. Are you sure `Img_Miss_List` has been initialized to more than an empty list? If you are using index assignment the list has to be at least length `i-1` if you want to set the element `i`. Either initialize the list to be the same length: `Img_Miss_list = [None] * len(GmdMiss_List)`, or just append the elements to the empty list:

```py
Img_Miss_List = []
for file in GmdMiss_list:
   Img_Miss_List.append(
       np.array(cv2.imread(os.path.join(
           os.getcwd(), GmdMiss_Folder, file), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE))
```